# reading between two values

Tags: vbscript

I have to read between 2 values after asking the users if he want between the '' or not between.

Exemple if the user select 1 in the text

```
'Hi' My name is 'Kev'in and i'm happ'y' to be 'there'
```

he will have

```
'Hi' 'Kev' 'y' 'there'
```

in a text file. If he chose 2, he will have

```
My name is in and i'm happ to be
```

Right now I'm using

```
Do While objScriptFile.AtEndOfStream <> True
   strCurrentLine = objScriptFile.ReadLine
     intIsComment = InStr(1,strCurrentLine,"'")
   If intIsComment > 0 Then
     objCommentFile.Write strCurrentLine & vbCrLf
   End If
Loop
Else
```

For now it's only reading both of the value (between '' and not between) but I have no idea how to change it.

Comment: why `'Hi' 'Kev' 'y' 'there'` and why not `'Hi' 'Kev' 'm happ' ' to be '` what's the logic behind this?

Answer (score 1):

That's pretty simple, provided the delimiter is unique. Split the line at `'` and output either the even or the odd array elements, depending on whether 1 or 2 was chosen.

```
...
strCurrentLine = "'Hi' My name is 'Kev'in and i`m happ'y' to be 'there'"
arr  = Split(strCurrentLine, "'")

For i = choice To UBound(arr) Step 2
  objCommentFile.Write arr(i)
Next
...
```

The value of `choice` is your users' selection (either 1 or 2).

Note that for this to work the strings *must not* contain apostrophes anywhere else. As @Ekkehard.Horner pointed out in his comment you can't use the delimiter character elsewhere in the text (`i'm`), because otherwise it would be impossible to distinguish where it was intended to be a delimiter and where not.

Comment: Because of the `i'm` the problem is not 'simple', but 'impossible to solve'. You need different markers for quoting (pairwise: 'y') or deletions (single: i'm).

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner True.